# Let iOS pick the System Font Helvetica Neue or San Francisco in CSS

Tags: ios, css, fonts, uiwebview

Is it possible to specify a system font in a `CSS` targeted to iOS (to be displayed in a `UIWebView`), and get similar results as when designing with **Interface Builder**:

[image: IB Font Menu]

Can a `CSS` set *System*, *System+Weight* or *Text Styles* instead of `font-family:Helvetica Neue`:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
    body{font-family:Helvetica Neue; font-size:14;}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

---

**System**

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(), UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(), UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize()
```

**System+Weight**

As in `let mediumWeight = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)`

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight, UIFontWeightThin, UIFontWeightLight, UIFontWeightRegular, UIFontWeightMedium, UIFontWeightSemibold, UIFontWeightBold, UIFontWeightHeavy, UIFontWeightBlack
```

**Text Styles**

```
Body, Callout, Caption 1, Caption 2, Footnote, Headline, Subhead, Title 1, Title 2, Title 3
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> on iOS and OS X by using the “-apple-system” CSS value for the “font-family” CSS Property.

As noted on [webkit.org](https://www.webkit.org/blog/3709/using-the-system-font-in-web-content/), there are currently discussions in the w3c regarding standardizing this value so authors could simply specify **system**.

---

## System Font

**-apple-system** on iOS 9 & Safari OS X 10.11

Using `font-family:` **CSS** Property:

```
font-family: -apple-system;
font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; // iOS 8 compatible, credit: @MarcoBoschi
```

In context *(fallback to `HelveticaNeue` when `-apple-system` is undefined)*:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
    body{font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; font-size:17;}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

## Weight & Style

Using `font-weight:` **CSS** Property:

```
normal, bold, bolder, lighter
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900
```

Using `font-style:` **CSS** Property:

```
normal, italic
```

## Dynamic Font

**-apple-system-xxx** on iOS 8.4.

Using `font:` **CSS** Property (represent an entire style, including size and weight):

```
font: -apple-system-body
font: -apple-system-headline
font: -apple-system-subheadline
font: -apple-system-caption1
font: -apple-system-caption2
font: -apple-system-footnote
font: -apple-system-short-body
font: -apple-system-short-headline
font: -apple-system-short-subheadline
font: -apple-system-short-caption1
font: -apple-system-short-footnote
font: -apple-system-tall-body
```

In context:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
    body{font: -apple-system-body;}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32408973) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32408973).

Comment: I've tried to set the `font-family` to `-apple-system` but on iOS 8.4.1 (iPhone 5s) doesn't work and text is displayed in Times New Roman. Setting the `font` property works fine.

Comment: Use `font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue';`. This will pick `Helvetica`  when `-apple-system` is undefined, and `San Francisco` on iOS 9.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect, thank you.  Works perfectly for my app.

Comment: wow thanks a lot for this detailed answer, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To further expand upon the correct answer by @SwiftArchitect, I debugged an invisible font on an iOS device (iPhone 7 in Safari) using a Mac on Safari.  My font-family was:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {font-family: "blisslight", blisslight, "blissregular", blissregular, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

iOS disregarded all fallback fonts including Arial, so I ended up using this to make it work:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {font-family: -apple-system, "blisslight", blisslight, "blissregular", blissregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Safari did not render -apple-system as passable code until the new CSS was uploaded despite adding the new CSS in the Web Inspector.